# Questions about implementation of a global register allocator for the tiny c compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, time, compiler-theory, tcc

upcoming summer i will hopefully start writing my masters thesis and i have been quite busy looking for a thesis subject. I now have a pool of subjects that i am interested in and the one that struck me most is the implementation of a global register allocator for the tiny C compiler (graph coloring or linear scan).

So i wanted to drop by and ask if any of you has ever done this and if it is a feasible subject for a master thesis, or if it is too hard. I would also be very happy if you could direct me to any good literature about this subject(i already have the dragonbook).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ask your tutor, not the internet in general!

Whatever your thesis, you need:

1. a good tutor
2. to be best buddies with your tutor

   - and one way to do that is sucking up and asking them their opinion on such a critical decision
3. it must be fun - that's an important motivator - but it must also be something you're going to **excel** at

Its not fun to mess it up and grade poorly.  Its not cheap - or perhaps not even possible - to do it all again.

You have a few months before the thesis starts.  I'd say that you can lightly do a global reg allocator if you do a practice run now.

But whatever your thesis subject, you need to be committed.

Answer (score 2):

I have done some register allocation for a much easier language than C (for an undergraduate compilers course). It was pretty hard for me, but I didn't have much time. I would say your project is feasible for a master thesis.

An excellent book to read for compiler design and especially optimizations (including register allocation) is
[Advanced Compiler Design & Implementation](http://books.google.gr/books?id=Pq7pHwG1_OkC&dq=advanced+compiler+design+and+implementation&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=el&ei=k9NcS9DcE5WJ4QaR5OCDBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false).